# Php loop through categories (and generated urls for all post in)

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I am rather new to php (dont get much further than tweaking some code)
So what i want is for every category (except category id 1, which is uncategorized)
I want the category url + category name
And for each post within the category, i want the url + title  (loop max 3 times)

what i have so far is:

```
<div class="divs">
    <div class="divs">
        <div class="divs">
            <h3 class="divs">
                <a href="<?php echo get_category_link( "5" );?>">
                    <?php echo get_cat_name(5);?>
                </a>
            </h3>
        </div>

        <div class="divs">
            <ol>
                <?php
                    $args = array('category' => 5, 'post_type' =>  'post'); 
                    $postslist = get_posts($args);   
                    $i = 0; 

                    foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post);{if(++$i > 3) break;} 
                ?>  

                        <li> 
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                <?php the_title(); ?>
                            </a>
                       </li> 

                      <?php endforeach; ?> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</ol>
```

This does what i want perfectly,  except it does it only for category id 5 ofcourse.    Is there an easy way to make this loop for all categories?

Edit:
Basicly i want the code to look through all categories instead of just do it for category 5 (we add/remove categories, so hardcoding the numbers isn't usefull)

Comment: Whatever kind of code that is: what keeps you from gathering all category IDs and loop over them?

Comment: Go read up in the WP documentation on how to _exclude_ posts from a specific category, instead of selecting only those _in_ a specific one.

Comment: (You are creating faulty HTML there btw. - `ol` must not contain `div`, but for some reason you have several closing `</div>` tags there that you output before the closing `</ol>`. Should probably simply be the other way around.)

Comment: @nico,  i can gather the category ids, but they change all the time.  so making it hardcoded will be a pain down the road (hence why i want to find something that checks for every category id, and then do the rest)
cbroe, thnx for pointing out the html error, i overlooked that one :P

Comment: After all, you should not hardcode them. There should be a way of getting them from the database - maybe something as obvious as the [official documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_all_category_ids/) might help?

Comment: @nicohaase I see how i can get grab all categorie ids from there,  but i still have no clue how to add that in the code :P  (keep in mind,  i never coded in php before,  but this was thrown on my plate XD)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you don't want to hardcode the category IDs, you need to fetch them through `get_all_category_ids` and loop over the result. This could work:

```
<div class="divs">
    <div class="divs">
        <?php
        $categoryIds = get_all_category_ids();
        foreach($categoryIds as $categoryId): ?>
        <div class="divs">
            <h3 class="divs">
                <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($categoryId); ?>">
                    <?php echo get_cat_name($categoryId); ?>
                </a>
            </h3>
        </div>

        <div class="divs">
            <ol>
                <?php
                $args = array('category' => $categoryId, 'post_type' => 'post');
                $postslist = get_posts($args);
                $i = 0;

                foreach ($postslist as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
                    {
                        if (++$i > 3) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    ?>

                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thnx a lot man (had to change some stuff with my divs to make it work like intended) but that worked like a charm.  1 follow up question.
is it possible to either exclude 1 specific category,  or exclude empty categories?

Comment: Of course - just remove that ID from `$categoryIds` or check for it in the `foreach` loop. But I would advise you to have a look at a PHP tutorial for further questions like this - you will learn better from them

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<?php
$args = array( 'category__and' => array(2, 3, 4, 5), 'post_type' =>  'post' );
$i = 0; 
$postslist = get_posts( $args );   
foreach ($postslist as $post) {
    setup_postdata($post); 
    if (++$i > 4) break;
    ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li> 
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: That’s still category 5 only. Plus, if the overall amount of posts is to be limited, then that should be done inside the query already (can be done using `posts_per_page`), rather than selecting _everything_ and then breaking off the loop over that after x iterations.

Comment: The original code did everything,  except loop through all categories basicly.  the original code limited the output to 3 posts (that part all worked)  it is just cycling through all categories that i really have no clue how to do :(